# Making image views move to the left

Tags: ios, objective-c

What I want is when I press START, the platforms will show, but they will move to the left as well. So How can I do this? Here is the code of what happens when we start the game:

```
-(IBAction)Start:(id)sender{
    Start.hidden = YES;
    Exit.hidden = YES;
    HighScoreLabel.hidden = NO;
    Heli.hidden = NO;
    PowerUp.hidden = NO;

    Obstacle1.hidden = NO;
    Obstacle2.hidden = NO;
    Platform1.hidden = NO;
    Platform2.hidden = NO;
    Platform3.hidden = NO;
    Platform4.hidden = NO;

    Trap1Cactus1.hidden = NO;
    Trap1Cactus2.hidden = NO;
    Trap2Saw1.hidden = NO;
    Trap2Saw2.hidden = NO;

    WinOrLose.hidden = YES;
    Top.hidden = YES;
    Bottom.hidden = NO;

    TrapUpsideDown.hidden = NO;
    TrapUpsideDown2.hidden = NO;
    SuperJump.hidden = NO;

    SavedFromDeathLabel.hidden = NO;
    ExplosionIfSaved.hidden = NO;

    BirdMovement = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.05 target:self selector:@selector(ShipMoving) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];


    HigherJump = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.07 target:self selector:@selector(SuperJumping) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

    HighTrap.hidden = NO;
}
```

Comment: where is your shipmoving  method?

Comment: 1. What type of objects are all these variables? 2 How are they being positioned? We need to see what is happening in the timer methods and know what kind of objects you are dealing with in order to have any chance of offering useful advice.

Comment: Welcome to SO. your question is vague to the point of absurdity. You need to show the part of your header file that defines your objects, and also need to tell us if you're using auto-layout or resizing masks ("struts and springs") for resizing.

Answer (score 0):

You do not want to create short duration timers and move your view objects by small increments each time your timer(s) fire. You should look into UIView animation or CAAnimation objects. I would suggest starting out with UIView animation methods that start with `animateWithDuration`. They are much easier to use than CAAnimation (Core Animation) which is complex, tricky, and not that well documented.